# How are Square processing fees represented in RetrievePayment response?

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm looking for an explanation of how Square processing fees are represented in the response to RetrievePayment (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-v1transactions-retrievebankaccount).

I'd happily read a documentation page about it but I can't find one.

The API documentation describes a `processing_fee_money` field but doesn't give much information.

For example, are the other values in the response reduced because of the processing fee or are they shown in their full amounts?

Also, I'd like to see a real example.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how the processing fee is taken out, see this article: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5068

To clarify: in a United States eCommerce transaction ([which is 2.9% + 30 cent](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/payments-pricing#pricing-for-online-and-in-app-payment-handling)), if you charged a customer $10 and then they left a $2 tip, your transaction would look like:

```
10 + 2 = $12
12 * 0.029 = 0.35 (after rounding)
0.35 + 0.30 = 0.65
```

So the `processing_fee_money` should show $0.65 in this scenario, and the tip and total collected should remain the same ($2, $10 respectively). Also see how we round [here](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5092-rounding).